# zsh auto completion didn't work properly with sudo prefix

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

### Definitions

I use `micro` as text editor. It's installed by `snap install micro --classic`

I use oh-my-zsh

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

### How to reproduce

When I write

```sh
mic
```

and press `tab`, then i get proper auto completion:

```sh
micro
```

but if i do following:

```
sudo mic
```

and press `tab` then it does not auto complete at all.

### My investigations

I tried to repeat problem with `nano` editor, but all works fine.
Additionally I tried to repeat problem on other linux OS and found that same version of oh-my-zsh, zsh and micro installed same way on Arch Linux works as expected with no problem.

PATH environment variable contains snap bin directory

visudo config secure_path contains snap bin directory

### Question

How to fix auto completion with sudo prefix?

Comment: See whether one of the suggestions posted [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7985820.html)  work for you, and if they do, please add it here as an answer, so that other users can also profit from this.

Comment: I don't want to do so, because it's crutch. Same version of oh-my-zsh, zsh and micro installed same way on arch linux works as expected.